# Google Cloud Storage + Function: System architecture at scale

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

### Background

I have a processing chain with 3 steps. I going to design my application to have a very high output.

### Getting into details

The system is solving incoming tasks. Each processing chain (`A`, `B` and `C`) has input and output:

`A` input is a task to be solved. `A` output is a list of sub tasks to be solved. `A` produces multiple outputs for a single input (all related to the same task).

`B` input is a task to be solved. `B` output is a single task targeted to `C`.

`C` input are list of messages, aggregated by the "parent task". Once all the items for a specific tasks is completely solved, `C` mark the task as completed.

Diagram:
[image]

One possible architecture, using Google Cloud, is to write a Google Cloud Storage Object into a bucket for every new incoming task. Turn on Google Function notification for each new storage object created. This function will to the work of `A` (from the processing chain). The output will be written into diffrent bucket that will fire another Function notification (`B`). The output will be written into a 3rd bucket for processing of `C`.

Note: When a function process a task, it also delete it on the end.

Let's assume that a specific task was created 10 items to process on Function `B`. So, in bucket `C` you will find, at the end, 10 different objects. Function `C` mission is to detect the exact time when ALL the items (`A` output) for a specific task was completely executed. If all the items executed, `C` has to mark the task as completed.

### The Problem

Sounds like we have to count how many outputs `A` had, and compare it to how many inputs `C` had.

Is this possible to change the system design to prevent the need of "counting messages"?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to have a look to [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows) product. In your design,

- Keep the function A but update it to send a JSON list of B task to run.
- Then, [iterate over the A JSON array response](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax#iterating_through_an_array) and use parallel executor to run, in parallel, the B tasks. i wrote [an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/parallel-executions-with-google-workflows-3a16f8fee0eb)
- When all the B tasks are finished, the C function can be called by Workflows.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand all context, requirements and scope restrictions/complications, but I would suggest to go through couple of StackOverflow questions and a Medium article to start with.

[How to combine multiple files in GCS bucket with Cloud Function trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238268/how-to-combine-multiple-files-in-gcs-bucket-with-cloud-function-trigger)

[How to concatenate sharded files on Google Cloud Storage automatically using Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-write-to-a-single-shard-on-google-cloud-storage-efficiently-using-cloud-dataflow-and-cloud-3aeef1732325)

[Google Cloud Platform solution for serverless log ingestion (files downloading) from a SFTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050709/google-cloud-platform-solution-for-serverless-log-ingestion-files-downloading)

I think those questions (and discussions) won't provide a complete answer on your question, but should expose some ideas on how a "state machine" can be supported in the idempotent world of cloud functions.